# FizzBuzz Neural Network

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, neural-network

### Approximating FizzBuzz

I am trying to approximate the infamous FizzBuzz function:

```
def fizzbuzz(start, end):
    a = list()
    for i in range(start, end + 1):
        a.append(fb(i))
    return a


def fb(i):
    if i % 3 == 0 and i % 5 == 0:
        return "FizzBuzz"
    elif i % 3 == 0:
        return "Fizz"
    elif i % 5 == 0:
        return "Buzz"
    else:
        return i
```

The problem is, after training, I am getting only numbers as output for all values between 1 and 100:

```
[  1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9  10  11  12  13  14  15  16  17  18
  19  20  21  22  23  24  25  26  27  28  29  30  31  32  33  34  35  36
  37  38  39  40  41  42  43  44  45  46  47  48  49  50  51  52  53  54
  55  56  57  58  59  60  61  62  63  64  65  66  67  68  69  70  71  72
  73  74  75  76  77  78  79  80  81  82  83  84  85  86  87  88  89  90
  91  92  93  94  95  96  97  98  99 100]
```

The correct output should instead be:

```
['1' '2' 'Fizz' '4' 'Buzz' 'Fizz' '7' '8' 'Fizz' 'Buzz' '11' 'Fizz' '13'
 '14' 'FizzBuzz' '16' '17' 'Fizz' '19' 'Buzz' 'Fizz' '22' '23' 'Fizz'
 'Buzz' '26' 'Fizz' '28' '29' 'FizzBuzz' '31' '32' 'Fizz' '34' 'Buzz'
 'Fizz' '37' '38' 'Fizz' 'Buzz' '41' 'Fizz' '43' '44' 'FizzBuzz' '46' '47'
 'Fizz' '49' 'Buzz' 'Fizz' '52' '53' 'Fizz' 'Buzz' '56' 'Fizz' '58' '59'
 'FizzBuzz' '61' '62' 'Fizz' '64' 'Buzz' 'Fizz' '67' '68' 'Fizz' 'Buzz'
 '71' 'Fizz' '73' '74' 'FizzBuzz' '76' '77' 'Fizz' '79' 'Buzz' 'Fizz' '82'
 '83' 'Fizz' 'Buzz' '86' 'Fizz' '88' '89' 'FizzBuzz' '91' '92' 'Fizz' '94'
 'Buzz' 'Fizz' '97' '98' 'Fizz' 'Buzz']
```

My neural network is classifying each number into one of four categories:

```
0. "Fizz"
1. "Buzz"
2. "FizzBuzz"
3. None of the above
```

I think my NN is learning to categorize each number to a class that is most frequently labeled as the correct class (which is #3: None of the above), and I don't know how to fix this issue.

### Preparing Data

I am encoding the X (input) values as 16-bit binary:

```
def binary_encode_16b_array(a):
    encoded_a = list()
    for elem in a:
        encoded_a.append(binary_encode_16b(elem))
    return np.array(encoded_a)


def binary_encode_16b(val):
    bin_arr = list()
    bin_str = format(val, '016b')
    for bit in bin_str:
        bin_arr.append(bit)
    return np.array(bin_arr)
```

And encoding the Y (output) values as one-hot vectors:

```
def one_hot_encode_array(a):
    encoded_a = list()
    for elem in a:
        encoded_a.append(one_hot_encode(elem))
    return np.array(encoded_a)


def one_hot_encode(val):
    if val == 'Fizz':
        return np.array([1, 0, 0, 0])
    elif val == 'Buzz':
        return np.array([0, 1, 0, 0])
    elif val == 'FizzBuzz':
        return np.array([0, 0, 1, 0])
    else:
        return np.array([0, 0, 0, 1])
```

which will categorize the 16-bit binary input data as one of the 4 possible categories specified by the FizzBuzz rule.

For example, if `[ 0.03 -0.4 -0.4  0.4]` is returned, the program knows not to print any of "Fizz", "Buzz", or "FizzBuzz":

```
# decoding values of Y
def one_hot_decode_array(x, y):
    decoded_a = list()
    for index, elem in enumerate(y):
        decoded_a.append(one_hot_decode(x[index], elem))
    return np.array(decoded_a)


def one_hot_decode(x, val):
    index = np.argmax(val)
    if index == 0:
        return 'Fizz'
    elif index == 1:
        return 'Buzz'
    elif index == 2:
        return 'FizzBuzz'
    elif index == 3:
        return x
```

### Initializing Data

This is how I am dividing up the training and testing data:

```
# train with data that will not be tested
test_x_start = 1
test_x_end = 100
train_x_start = 101
train_x_end = 10000

test_x_raw = np.arange(test_x_start, test_x_end + 1)
test_x = binary_encode_16b_array(test_x_raw).reshape([-1, 16])
test_y_raw = fizzbuzz(test_x_start, test_x_end)
test_y = one_hot_encode_array(test_y_raw)

train_x_raw = np.arange(train_x_start, train_x_end + 1)
train_x = binary_encode_16b_array(train_x_raw).reshape([-1, 16])
train_y_raw = fizzbuzz(train_x_start, train_x_end)
train_y = one_hot_encode_array(train_y_raw)
```

so the model trains using values between 101 and 10000 and tests using values between 1 and 100.

### Neural Network Model

My model architecture is simple, with 100 hidden neurons in one layer:

```
# define params
input_dim = 16
output_dim = 4
h1_dim = 100

# build graph
X = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, input_dim])
Y = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, output_dim])

h1_w = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([input_dim, h1_dim]))
h1_b = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([h1_dim]))
h1_z = tf.nn.relu(tf.matmul(X, h1_w) + h1_b)

fc_w = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([h1_dim, output_dim]))
fc_b = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([output_dim]))
Z = tf.matmul(h1_z, fc_w) + fc_b

# define cost
cross_entropy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(labels=Y, logits=Z))

# define op
train_step = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(0.005).minimize(cross_entropy)

# define accuracy
correct_prediction = tf.equal(tf.argmax(Z, 1), tf.argmax(Y, 1))
correct_prediction = tf.cast(correct_prediction, tf.float32)
accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(correct_prediction)
```

### Running the Model

For the sake of simplicity, I opted to omit batch training:

```
with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())

    for i in range(1000):
        sess.run(train_step, feed_dict={X: train_x, Y: train_y})

        train_accuracy = sess.run(accuracy, feed_dict={X: train_x, Y: train_y})
        print(i, ":", train_accuracy)

    output = sess.run(Z, feed_dict={X: test_x})
    decoded = one_hot_decode_array(test_x_raw, output)
    print(decoded)
```

During training, the value of accuracy fails to go above `0.533333`. The network is being trained to only output numbers per rule `!(i%3==0 || i%5==0) ? i`, which is the most common answer for the FizzBuzz function.

### Edit: Solved

Using the solution provided by @Blender below, I changed the initializers for both the hidden and output layer to be uniform random. Increasing the number of iterations and lowering the learning rate of AdamOptimizer, my model now works perfectly on the test dataset. I've uploaded the source code of the working model [in a GitHub repository](https://github.com/Jaewan-Yun/fizzbuzz_neural_network).

Comment: Neural networks can learn to represent arbitrary functions, but only if there is a high enough density of training data. Your data shows you are trying to do extrapolation rather than interpolation, which is one problem. Another issue is that you are using a naive feedforward network that in no way tries to incorporate any prior information about your domain, e.g. that modulos are important for the task at hand.

Comment: Use `[x % 3 == 0, x % 5 == 0]` as your feature vector to determine if your feature vector is the problem or if it's some fundamental problem with your architecture.

Comment: Glad to hear you have solved this, because it might come up in your next interview: http://joelgrus.com/2016/05/23/fizz-buzz-in-tensorflow/

Comment: @imran Thanks sharing that link. I was thoroughly entertained by his presentation. His code is certainly more concise and elegant than mine. I just learned a lot of pythonic styling from his code :)

Comment: @imran I noticed that, in your link, the binary_encode method is printing out [1, 0, 0, 0] for `binary_encode(i=1, num_digits=4)`. While this won't affect model performance, the correct binary representation should instead be `np.flip(binary_encode(1, 4), axis=0)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Setting all of the initial weights to the same value (zero) in your network negates any benefit to having multiple neurons in a layer. Randomly initializing the weights is necessary:

```
h1_w = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([input_dim, h1_dim], stddev=0.1))
```

The accuracy only begins to change after about 200 iterations for me but gives 0.99 for the test set after 1,000 iterations. I'm a little surprised this even works with only a single hidden layer.